# embellish on the theme of

Tags: expressions, terminology

Thesis-writer and native speaker here.  My advisor did not like my use of the phrase "embellish on the theme of," insisting that the verb "embellish" cannot be used that way.  I think I first learned the phrase during piano lessons as a kid, and I've used it in my brain-thoughts thousands of time, but now I'm not sure if it's too jargony for a math thesis.  Can anyone point me to non-musical sources that use this phrase?  Or perhaps another version of this phrase that requires less musical knowledge?

Additional context: I searched for "embellish on the theme of" (with quotes) in Google and it returned only 3 results.  That surprises me.

Comment: I believe that musically, one more typically *improvises on a theme*.

Comment: Hmm... but you can "embellish a melody," yes?

Comment: I would say so, yes. That should also mean to change it a little in some custom fashion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your advisor is correct. You [embellish](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/embellish) a theme, (direct object) not on it (prepositional object).

Perhaps you are confusing it with "elaborate"? You could elaborate on a theme.

Comment: A prepositional object is not the same thing as an indirect object. When you give a dog a bone, you have an indirect object, but when give a bone to a dog, there is none.

Comment: I must have been mixing it with "improvise on.".  Thanks!  (By the way, his objection was not to the preposition, but rather my use of embellish in that context...)